# Multilevel propensity score

Tags: experiment-design, confounding, propensity-scores, medicine

I'm trying to analyze many treatments on outcome after propensity score 1:1 matching.

My problem: I have 6 differents drugs and each patient can take or not each of these. If I build my propensity score on treatments assignment, this variable will have $2^6$ levels.

I read somewhere that it's correct to include in the propensity score the variables (potential confounders) that affect the outcome (that is binary in my study). Do you think it could solve my problem?

Comment: This post might be of interest: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202698/comparing-two-or-more-treatments-with-inverse-probablity-of-treatment-weighting/203771#203771